# PDFSharp not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to save my bitmaps in a `.pdf` file. It doesn't work. I'm not getting an error, but it doesn't open the dialog to save the `.pdf` file.

Here is my code:

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();

for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt < nPaginasPDF; iCnt++)
{
    doc.Pages.Add(new PdfPage());
    XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[iCnt]);
    XImage img = XImage.FromFile("C:\\" + (iCnt+1) + ".bmp"); (In this directory have these image files)

    xgr.DrawImage(img, panel1.ClientRectangle);
}

using (var Stream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile())
{
    doc.Save(Stream);
}

doc.Close();
```

Comment: have you stepped through the code to confirm that saveFileDialog1.OpenFile() is executed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `SaveFileDialog`'s `OpenFile` method opens the file returned by `SaveFileDialog.Filename` property file with read/write permission.

To select a file before saving, you must use the `ShowDialog` method first. Have you debugged and checked the value of `Stream` with a break point?

Comment: I have forgot  `if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)`
Thanks a lot. It works